# resize image while keeping ratio

Tags: php, image, math, resize

I found this function on google but it isn't working. I tested with a 818x800 image and the function will return the same size. What's wrong ?

```
function imageResize($width, $height, $target) {
//takes the larger size of the width and height and applies the formula accordingly...this is so this script will work  dynamically with any size image
if ($width > $height) {
$percentage = ($target / $width);
} else {
$percentage = ($target / $height);
}
//gets the new value and applies the percentage, then rounds the value
$width = round($width * $percentage);
$height = round($height * $percentage);
//returns the new sizes in html image tag format...this is so you can plug this function inside an image tag and just get the
return "width=\"$width\" height=\"$height\"";
```

}

```
$mysock = getimagesize("http://www.pirate-punk.com/pochette.php?i=ZGwvcHAvNjI1MC84NiBDcmV3IC0gMjAwMCAtIEJhZCBCYWQgUmVnZ2FlLnppcCM4IDYgQ3JldyAtIEJhZCBCYWQgUmVnZ2FlLWZyb250ICBbd3d3LlBpcmF0ZS1QdW5rLm5ldF0uanBnCg==");
echo "<img src=\"$pochetteimg\" ";
imageResize($mysock[0], $mysock[1], 300);
echo ">";
```

I'm trying to resize the image to 300px width while keeping the ratio

Comment: there should be `echo` here `imageResize($mysock[0], $mysock[1], 300);`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function imageResize($width, $height, $target) {
if ($width > $height) { $percentage = ($target / $width); } else { $percentage = ($target / $height); }
$width = round($width * $percentage);
$height = round($height * $percentage);
return "width=\"$width\" height=\"$height\"";
}

$mysock = getimagesize("pochette.jpg");
$size = imageResize($mysock[0], $mysock[1], 300);
echo "<img src=\"pochette.jpg\" ".$size." />";
?>
```

Try it like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
$mysock = getimagesize("YourUrl");
echo "<img src='" . $pochetteimg . "' " . imageResize($mysock[0], $mysock[1], 300) . "/>";
```

Answer (score 0):

The `imageresize` function is not actually resizing the image. Its just returning the width and height of the image maintaining the aspect ratio. Is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I was not allowed to make a comment at that moment. May be because my reputation was not enough.

Comment: That would be so nice of you! :)